# TCPDF: Opening print window after output pdf doesn't works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, tcpdf

I would automatically open print window after PDF output

I've seen this example
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_053/

It works in Firefox, but it doesn't work in Chrome
can anyone help me?

Comment: The function was deliberately removed by chrome. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895126/chrome-77-not-auto-printing-pdfs . Chrome allows print only in response to a user gesture